# Singleton instantiated with double-checked blocking method

Tags: java, concurrency, singleton

I have a question about this instantiation method:

From [this](http://www.oodesign.com/singleton-pattern.html) web site it says:

```
class Singleton
{
    private static Singleton instance;

    private Singleton()
    {
    System.out.println("Singleton(): Initializing Instance");
    }

    public static Singleton getInstance()
    {
        if (instance == null)
        {
            synchronized(Singleton.class)
            {
                if (instance == null)
                {
                    System.out.println("getInstance(): First time getInstance was invoked!");
                    instance = new Singleton();
                }
            }            
        }

        return instance;
    }

    public void doSomething()
    {
        System.out.println("doSomething(): Singleton does something!");
    }
}
```

However from the book "Head First Design Pattern" by Elisabeth Freeman, Eric Freeman, Bert Bates, Kathy Sierra, Elisabeth Robson, they instantiate the Singleton using the same method, with the only difference that they declare the private static member as `volatile` and they rim the point  quite a bit about declaring it `volatile`. Should not be enough declaring the "critical zone" synchronized in order to establish the proper "happnens-before relationship" between threads?

Comment: Not an answer to your question - but in Java the preferred method of doing Singletons is not the Double Checked pattern - the preferred method is to use enums - http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=46

Comment: Your code is a broken DCL pattern

Comment: Jon Skeet [mentions](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Singleton.aspx) that double-checked locking is broken in Java (without `volatile`).

Comment: @assylias who are you talking to, user93353 or Rollerball?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the defininition, using volatile variables reduces the risk of memory consistency errors, because any write to a volatile variable establishes a happens-before relationship with subsequent reads of that same variable.

The problem is that an out-of-order write may allow the instance reference to be returned before the Singleton constructor is executed.

1. Thread A notices that the value is not initialized, so it obtains the lock and begins to initialize the value.
2. Due to the semantics of programming languages, the code generated by the compiler is allowed to update the shared variable to point to a partially constructed object before A has finished performing the initialization. For example, in Java if a call to a constructor has been inlined then the shared variable may immediately be updated once the storage has been allocated but before the inlined constructor initializes the object.
3. Thread B notices that the shared variable has been initialized (or so it appears), and returns its value. Because thread B believes the value is already initialized, it does not acquire the lock. If B uses the object before all of the initialization done by A is seen by B (either because A has not finished initializing it or because some of the initialized values in the object have not yet percolated to the memory B uses (cache coherence)), the program will likely crash.

Read this wiki for a clear explanation of things: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_checked_locking_pattern#Usage_in_Java

Comment: No chances that in JDK7 it's possible to use it without volatile? just curious

Comment: @Rollerball The Java Memory Model has not significantly changed between Java 5 and 7. You need to use volatile in that situation, although there are other preferred idioms to create a thread safe singleton.